# .htaccess - redirect domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain name **www.domainA.com** I want to redirect it to **domainB** in following manner.

`www.domainA.com` -> `www.domainB.com` 
`www.domainA.com/anything` -> `www.domainB.com/rebrand`

How I can do this in htaccess, I have done following code but it redirecting to `/rebrand/` only.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/
RewriteRule ^\/$ http://www.domainB.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/rebrand/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URIs that go through rules in an htaccess file has the leading slash stripped off, so you can't match against it. For the second rule, it's matching the `/` request because the first rule isn't being applied and your regex matches anything or nothing, you can fix that by changing the `*` to `+`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domainB.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.domainB.com/rebrand/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting through htaccess is tricky sometimes, there are many ways of implementing this but there is one simple way which worked for me

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (.*) [newdomain.com...] [R=301,L]
```

You can get more info from [webmaster world forum](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3242480.htm)